# The newly added column is not considered in the groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame `top15` with country names as indices and several columns. 
I'm trying to add a new column computed from two existing ones, but it's not considered by the groupby object (groups by continent).
This is what I'm doing:

- I tried two approaches to create a new column and printing the DataFrame shows the POPEST column:

`top15['POPEST'] = top15['Energy Supply'] / top15['Energy Supply per Capita']`

`top15 = top15.assign(POPEST=[top15['Energy Supply'] / top15['Energy Supply per Capita']])`

After grouping the POPEST column (which is the only one I'm interested in) does not appear when computing any function:

```py
ContinentDict  = {'China':'Asia', 
                  'United States':'North America', 
                  'Japan':'Asia', 
                  'United Kingdom':'Europe', 
                  'Russian Federation':'Europe', 
                  'Canada':'North America', 
                  'Germany':'Europe', 
                  'India':'Asia',
                  'France':'Europe', 
                  'South Korea':'Asia', 
                  'Italy':'Europe', 
                  'Spain':'Europe', 
                  'Iran':'Asia',
                  'Australia':'Australia', 
                  'Brazil':'South America'}
grouped = top15.groupby(by=ContinentDict)
print(grouped.sum())
```

This outputs every the sum of all the values based on the country and its continent except the POPEST column.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: top15 is the result of parsing and merging different excel/csv files, the columns are: 
`['Rank', 'Documents', 'Citable documents', 'Citations', 'Self-citations', 'Citations per document', 'H index', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']`

And the rows are the 15 countries listed in the `ContinentDict` keys.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of top15?

Comment: @run-out I've edited the post

Comment: I've recreated the example using the first approach and it is working fine. You must have an error not included in the question somewhere.

Comment: Thank you @run-out I'll try again